# Test Driven Development (TDD): Writing unit tests in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, tdd, xcode4

I am keen to write a library project with tests, even if I then include the code in other projects (as opposed to linking to the lib.) for inclusion on ios projects.

It seems checking the 'Include unit tests' isn't enough for xcode 4 to properly initialise a project with tests, and after looking through the Apple documentation I can't find anything relevant.

Does anybody know of any resources or tutorials for getting this working?

Even with the default Cocoa Touch Static Library project, upon choosing "Test" from the "Product" menu, it fails (when linking) with this error (the project is called `test1`):

```
library not found for -ltest1
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I finally got this working.

The trick was to create the library without checking the 'Include unit tests' option in XCode 4.  Then I created a new target myself.

(in xcode 4)

1. Create a new Cocoa Touch Static Library project and DON'T check "Include Unit Tests"
2. Select the project in the navigator
3. Go into the "Build Phases" tab
4. Click 'Add Target' and choose 'Cocoa Touch Unit Testing Bundle'
5. Go through the wizard until the target is created
6. Then go in the "Product" menu and choose "Edit Scheme..."
7. Make sure your project (not the test target) is selected and, select "Test"
8. Click + to add a new target
9. Choose your test project and click Add
10. Now press Cmd+U (this is the shortcut for "Product > Test" menu item) and you'll notice the default test fails.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I got tests working in new project with 'Include unit tests' under Xcode 4 build 4A251a (GM Seed). But does it really work so that to see failing tests I have to manually open the console after each test run and scan the output?!

Comment: The way I solved it, failed tests appear as errors in xcode.  So you can see them in the Issues tab and jump to them etc.

Comment: It was fixed for me in the final release of Xcode 4. (There was a second GM seed IIRC...)

Comment: I continue to experience this issue in XCode 4.0.2 but the answer above worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree.. this is unneeded in the latest version of XCode